# get update panel cause post back in pageLoad event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

How I can determine what update panel cause postback in `function pageLoad()` event?

my `pageLoad` evenet fires twice and I think it happend bacause of my 2 update panels

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tell this from the __EVENTTARGET form field.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the [`BeginRequest`-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) instead and use the [`get_updatePanelsToUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216366.aspx) method to get the ID(s) of the `UpdatePanel`(s) that should re-render their content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(onBeginRequest);

    function onBeginRequest(sender, args) {
        var updatePanelID = args.get_updatePanelsToUpdate();
    }
</script>
```